# Higher/Lower Card Number guessing game

Tags: python

My Tutor has set us a task: Create a higher/lower number guessing game with random integers. We must ask the user for a maximum value to generate and how many values we want to play.

For example:

```
max value: 12
number of values: 6

3 Hi(H) Lo(L):H
7 Hi(H) Lo(L):L
9 Hi(H) Lo(L):L
12 Hi(H) Lo(L):L
10 Hi(H) Lo(L):L
4
Your score is:4
```

The code I tried:

```
import random

print("This program plays out HI/LO game with random integer values")

mx_val = int(input("Enter maximun value: "))
num_val = int(input("Enter how many values to play(less than max value): "))

print("Get ready to play the game")

a = []

while len(a) != num_val:
    r = random.randint(1, mx_val)
    if r not in a:
        a.append(r)

score = 0

for i in a:
    print(a[0], end=" ")
    guess = input("Enter Hi(H)or Lo(L): ")
    while guess != "H" and guess != "L":
        guess = input("You must enter 'H' or 'L': ")

    if guess == "H" and a[1] > a[0]:
        score += 1

    if guess == "L" and a[1] < a[0]:
        score += 1

    a.pop(0)

print("Final score is ", score)
```

This is my code but it does not ask the right amount of questions. It's always way short.

Comment: you may want to take look here https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. Questions have to be spefic regarding a problem in your code not the functionality.

Answer (score 0):

- Do not iterate over list and remove items from that list at the same time
- It's not enough values in your `a` list. You need to increase it by one

Code:

```
import random

print("This program plays out HI/LO game with random integer values")

mx_val = int(input("Enter maximun value: "))
num_val = int(input("Enter how many values to play(less than max value): "))

print("Get ready to play the game")

a = []

while len(a) != num_val+1:
    r = random.randint(1, mx_val)
    if r not in a:
        a.append(r)

score = 0

for i in range(num_val):
    print(a[0], end=" ")
    guess = input("Enter Hi(H)or Lo(L): ")
    while guess != "H" and guess != "L":
        guess = input("You must enter 'H' or 'L': ")

    if guess == "H" and a[1] > a[0]:
        score += 1

    if guess == "L" and a[1] < a[0]:
        score += 1

    a.pop(0)

print("Final score is ", score)
```

Output:

```
This program plays out HI/LO game with random integer values
Enter maximun value: 12
Enter how many values to play(less than max value): 6
Get ready to play the game
10 Enter Hi(H)or Lo(L): H
4 Enter Hi(H)or Lo(L): L
8 Enter Hi(H)or Lo(L): H
7 Enter Hi(H)or Lo(L): L
9 Enter Hi(H)or Lo(L): H
11 Enter Hi(H)or Lo(L): L
Final score is  2
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. But I need it to print the final value aswell without asking for Hi Lo. For example. 11 Enter Hi(H) or Lo(L): L . 3